# Higher-Order Procedure - pair construction (cons, car, cdr)

Tags: scheme, procedure, cons, cdr

i need to create this procedures: my-cons, my-car, my-cdr in Scheme.

It should work like this:

> (define p1 (my-cons 3 8))
>
> (p1 #t)
>
> 3
>
> (p1 #f)
>
> 8
>
> (my-car p1)
>
> 3
>
> (my-cdr p1)
>
> 8

now, I have only this:

> (define my-cons
>
> (lambda (x y)
>
> (cons x y)
>
> (let ((a (car (cons x y))))
>
> ```
>  (lambda (a)
>   (if (equal? a #f) y x)))))
> ```

but in this code i can't apply my-cons or my-cdr on defined p1
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's some extraneous code in `my-cons` which doesn't seem to belong here. This is enough:

```
(define my-cons
  (lambda (x y)
    (lambda (a)
      (if a x y))))
```

(Also, you don't need to compare a boolean value with `#t` or `#f` — it's usable in `if` as it is.)

Now you have `my-cons` that returns a function which returns either `x` or `y` depending on its arugment. You can use that when implementing `my-car` and `my-cdr`:

```
(define my-car
  (lambda (c)
    (c #t)))

(define my-cdr
  (lambda (c)
    (c #f)))
```

Comment: ohh it's nice, i thought that will be more difficult :)
but what about switch procedure? I have it in this form:
`(define switch
  (lambda p
    (cons (cdr p) (car p))))`

Comment: What's your question about it?

Comment: If `p1` is defined using `my-cons`, then it can't be unpacked using the standard `car` and `cdr`; you must use `my-car` and `my-cdr` on it.

Comment: Please post the console log of how you're trying to use it, and what error you are getting.

Comment: oh sorry, the switch proc is ok, but the line after. I'm trying this: `(define p1 (my-cons 3 8))
(define p2 (switch p1))
(my-car p2)`

and the error msg: application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (8 . 3)
  arguments...:
   #t

Comment: Here, you're trying to unpack with `my-car` what's been packed with the ordinary `cons` inside `switch`.